# Why is the end xml tag not parsing properly?

Tags: java, string, xml-parsing

I'm having issues parsing this line of XML text:

```
<Index>1</Index><Price>$18.38</Price><Product>Takis Fuego, 1 Ounce (46 Pack)</Product><SoldBy> Sam's Club</SoldBy><href>https://www.google.com/shopping/product/14559077146163012667?hl=en&sxsrf=ALiCzsb1Gfl32-pXt32h0QkkE-T57FtdxA:1670964406762&psb=1&q=takis&prds=eto:15330784880350744537_0,pid:15387764403936018691,rsk:PC_15179594788466925291&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPgJuOvsj-AhUJGlkFHSQsBpcQ8gIIpgooAA</href>
```

This is the code responsible for parsing the text:

```
`private static void buildGUIFile() throws IOException {
        
        List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(fileName);
        for (int i = 0; i < (fileLines.size()); i++) {
            resNum = i + 1;
            int beginIndex = fileLines.indexOf("<Price>");
            int endIndex = fileLines.indexOf("</Price>");
            try {

price = fileLines.get(i).trim().substring(fileLines.indexOf(<Price>".trim()) + "<Price>".trim().length(), fileLines.indexOf("</Price>".trim()));

            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("endIndex" + endIndex);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`
This is the code that formats each product in fileName:
`public String xmlString() {
        String str = "<Index>" + resultNum + "</Index>" + "<Price>" + Price + "</Price>" + "<Product>" + Product
                + "</Product>" + "<SoldBy> " + Company + "</SoldBy>" + "<href>" + link + "</href>";
        return str;
```

This is the stack trace when I run the program, calling the fileName:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 6, end -1, length 355
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4601)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2704)
    at SeerWebCrawler.buildGUIFile(SeerWebCrawler.java:133)
    at SeerWebCrawler.main(SeerWebCrawler.java:58)
```

Now specifically the endindex of the substring appears to be what's causing the problem, I just don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please print out the value of "fileLines.get(i)". I am afraid the value of "fileLines.get(i)"  is not the one you mentioned.

Comment: You should really use an XML parser.

Comment: Okay, sure but can you tell me why I'm having the error so I have something to work with Mark? This is the second program that i'm using XML tags in, so I cant understand why </Price><Product> in my xml tag is giving me a error?

Comment: Stone, the fileLines.get(i) is returning a string representation of product. Specifically:  it returns <Index>1</Index><Price>$18.38</Price><Product>Takis Fuego, 1 Ounce (46 Pack)</Product><SoldBy> Sam's Club</SoldBy><href>https://www.google.com/shopping/product/14559077146163012667?hl=en&sxsrf=ALiCzsb1Gfl32-pXt32h0QkkE-T57FtdxA:1670964406762&psb=1&q=takis&prds=eto:15330784880350744537_0,pid:15387764403936018691,rsk:PC_15179594788466925291&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPgJuOvsj-AhUJGlkFHSQsBpcQ8gIIpgooAA</href> when i = 0. The index tag starts at one.

Comment: You are doing `fileLines.get(i)` to get one line and then `fileLines.indexOf("</Price>")` which searches all the lines, which seems wrong - what is `fileLines`, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, so what I'm trying to do is make my program read a .txt file containing a list of products. Each product is one line in the file with xml tags used to separate each part of the product.  After each line is read, its put into a list of strings I'm calling fileLines. So specifically: I'm retrieving 1 product as a string, breaking down the line using `substring();` with  `filelines.indexOf();` to refer to the start and end of the substring containing the price.

Comment: Well, do you see the problem? `fileLines` is a _list of multiple strings_. You get the _string_ at index i. Then you try to find "</Price>" in the _list_ instead of within the _string_ itself.

Comment: Then why is my starting index `<Price>` fine, its in the same substring?

Comment: It's not. `fileLines.indexOf("<Price>".trim()) + "<Price>".trim().length()` -> indexOf give you -1 again + the length of the string (7) gives you 6 (as shown in your error) but it should be 16 based on your actual string.

Comment: Why not using an XM parser again?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was annoyingly simple: Each time the loop executes the program looks at a string in the list `fileLines` to parse the data.

The problem occurs when I set the start and end lengths of the index, I needed to include `get(i)` to the command to make sure it was looking at a specific line:

```
int psi = fileLines.get(i).indexOf("<Price>");
int pei = fileLines.get(i).indexOf("</Price>");
price = fileLines.get(i).substring(psi + "<Price>".length(), pei);
System.out.println(price);
```

Sorry if I did not explain myself well.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a method to parse the value within the `Price` element.
I'm using `+ 7` here, because the length of the text, `<Price>`, is 7 characters.

```java
String price(String xml) {
    return xml.substring(xml.indexOf("<Price>") + 7, xml.indexOf("</Price>"));
}
```

You can then utilize the method from within your `buildGUIFile`, as follows.

```java
private static void buildGUIFile() throws IOException {
    List<String> fileLines = Files.readAllLines(fileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < (fileLines.size()); i++) {
        resNum = i + 1;
        price = price(fileLines.get(i).trim());
    }
}
```

Furthermore, if you wanted the `price` method to return a `float` or `double` value, you could use the following.

```java
float price(String xml) {
    String string = xml.substring(xml.indexOf("<Price>") + 8, xml.indexOf("</Price>"));
    return Float.parseFloat(string);
}
```